# C++ int comparison efficiency

Tags: c++, performance, comparison

Is there any difference in the performance of the following code snippets? Which one performs best and why?

```
int i = 1000000000;

while(i != 0) { i--; }
```

or

```
int i = 1000000000;

while(i) { i--; }
```

or

```
int i = 1000000000;

while(i > 0) { i--; }
```

I see a lot of people use the first example and wonder why. Easier to read?

Comment: Why do people down vote instead of giving an normal answer or just look away? This i a normal question i think and where should he ask this questions?

Comment: The first two are equivalent; converting an `int` to a `bool` is the same as checking it it's not zero. As with literally every other performance question: 1) surely the work inside the loop dominates your time, so who cares? 2) to know if you should care, profile it, and 3) look at the compiled code if you must really know.

Comment: @retinotop I didn't vote either way, but OP didn't show their own research such as assembly output or benchmark results. Questions without effort are often looked down upon on this site. That said, I look down upon down votes that lack constructive criticism.

Comment: @retinotop I downvote such questions because questions about the performance of C++ code without benchmarks are not useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any difference in the performance of the following code snippets?

No.

First two are equivalent, and all three can be optimized to exactly same assembly.

> I see a lot of people use the first example and wonder why. Easier to read?

It requires the reader to know fewer language rules than the second one. In particular, the second program requires the knowledge that conditional expression is converted to `bool`, and that the conversion from `int` has the same result as inequality with zero.

Note that if `i` were replaced with a floating point number, or if the decrement were modified to have more complexity (for example: decrement by 2), then the third option would be easiest to prove correct. With integers and single decrement, there is no difference.

Answer (score 6):

They are all the same in this context and any decent compiler will generate equivalent code for all three.
In any case, trying to hand-optimize trivial things like this (integer comparisons) is pointless. Your compiler will figure it out and do a much better job during code-gen than you ever could. So just stop trying and instead just write the most *readable* code you can and then *trust the compiler* - in any case, none of this makes any performance difference.